# Test if audio jack is connected

Tags: vb.net, windows, audio

I've gone through a couple of threads now, and there doesn't seem to be an answer to this question in VB.

My code was to see if the headphone jack is connected or not. If it is connected, the audio will change to a value stored in a file. If not, it will take the last value, before it was changed, and set it to that. Fairly simple.

The issue is I cannot test if the 3.5 mm headphone jack is connected or not.

The current code I have tried: (using CoreAudio.dll)

```
Imports CoreAudio

Sub test()
    Dim DevEnum As New MMDeviceEnumerator()
    Dim device As MMDevice = DevEnum.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia)

    MessageBox.Show(Device.FriendlyName)
End Sub
```

This works, but doesn't give what I wanted as it only gives the name of the audio codec. Is there a way using the CoreAudio API or an alternative means to testing whether the headphone jack is occupied or not?

A link to the CoreAudio.dll file as it seems to be pretty hard to find,

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B51QM9jcqQK2MGFPTG5fa0FxNkk

(paste in project_name*/bin/debug)